# pyopencl: "clEnqueueReadBuffer failed: INVALID_VALUE"

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I have attempted to search for a solution or possible cause for this but I cant find anything.

Python 3.9 / pyopencl 2022.3.1

Getting Context / Queue:

```
PLATFORM = cl.get_platforms()[0]
DEVICE = PLATFORM.get_devices()[0]
CTX = cl.Context([DEVICE])
QUEUE = cl.CommandQueue(CTX)
```

Buffer Creation:

```
InputBuffer = cl.Buffer(CTX, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE, size=inputs.nbytes)
cl.enqueue_copy(QUEUE, InputBuffer, inputs).wait()
```

Faulty Code:

```
output = np.empty(InputBuffer.size, dtype=np.float32)    
cl._enqueue_read_buffer(QUEUE, InputBuffer, output)
```

InputBuffer is a Buffer object, with a size that can vary but with my current tests, 8.

P.S. InputBuffer is a test buffer but stores the same data as the OutputBuffer. Its just changed later in the code

What I want to happen is to store the data in the "buffer" to a numpy array named "output"

So far I have tried:
Using a different dtype (np.float64), No effect
Using .wait(), No effect

Currently raises this error:

```
cl._enqueue_read_buffer(QUEUE, InputBuffer, output)
pyopencl._cl.LogicError: clEnqueueReadBuffer failed: INVALID_VALUE
```